# Connection to a postgres cluster with the pgAdmin failed to complete

Tags: database, postgresql, database-connection, pgadmin

I am trying to connect to a postgreqs cluster with the pgAdmin, but even with the connection data being correct, pgAdmin returns the following error:

[image: Register server creation of pgAdmin returning a error]

The cluster exists and are online, port and hostname are correct, but I'm still getting this error, how can I solve this?

**Update**

Postgres version:15.0

Psql version:15.0

I can connect to server using psql

Comment: More information needed: 1) Postgres version? 2) pgAdmin4 version? 3) Can you connect to server using [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)? **Add information as update to quesrion**.

Comment: Except you did not include `pgAdmin4` version which is the software you are having issues with.

Comment: I'm betting it is a pgAdmin4  version issue per here [Release Notes](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.15/release_notes.html) *Version 6.14 PostgreSQL: 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14* vs *Version 6.15 PostgreSQL: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15*.

Comment: I think you are using a version of pgAdmin which is not new enough to support PostgreSQL 15.

Comment: Changed the version of pgAdmin and everything worked out well, thank you guys for the help